# How to set an application wide variable? (on app controller?)

Tags: ember.js

I am using the latest Ember, 2.1, and am wondering how to set some application wide variables, such as user id, username, email, etc, presumably on the application controller.

While ember applications have tons of files, I haven't really done a lot yet, I'm somewhat confident I'm sharing just the right code. I don't have a login route file. I have the ember simple auth plugin installed, but I'm not actually using/invoking it any special way, except for mixing it into my application route:

```
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';
export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin)
```

My router:

```
this.route('login')
```

My login template:

```
<button {{action 'forceLogin'}}>Force login of devinrhode2@gmail.com by clicking this action button</button>
<p>Your account id is: {{account_id}}</p>
```

My login controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    forceLogin: () => {
      var data = {
        "account_id": 123,
        "email":"devinrhode2@gmail.com",
        "name":"Devin Rhode"
      }
      this.setProperties(data)
    }
  }
});
```

I have the `forceLogin` controller action being called, but, the `{{account_id}}` is not populating into the template. How could I get the account_id to render back into the template? How could I make the account_id globally accessible to my ember application by calling this.get('account_id') wherever I need it?

Currently I get the error:

```
 Cannot read property 'setProperties' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because of the way you define `forceLogin`. Arrow functions are bound to the context where they're defined. Here's what your code compiles to:

```
var _this = this; // we capture `this` from out here!
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    forceLogin() {
      ...
      _this.setProperties(data) // `_this` is the window!
    }
  }
});
```

That's no good because `this` should be the instance of the controller and instead it's the `window`.

Instead you should define `forceLogin` like this:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    forceLogin() {
      ...
      this.setProperties(data) // `this` is our controller instance
    }
  }
});
```

---

To get the `account_id` from somewhere else, you can inject the login controller:

```
// in some other controller
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  login: Ember.inject.controller(),

  actions: {
    doSomethingWithTheAccountId() {
      var accountId = this.get('login.account_id');
      ...
    }
  }
});
```

It would be cleaner to move those properties to a service, which you can inject anywhere with `Ember.inject.service()`

Comment: Thank you very much @dwickern. I was totally thinking that arrow functions are just syntactic sugar, so I would've been stuck on this for quite a while, looking in all the wrong places.

Comment: BTW.. really, what I should do, is be setting this variables on ember-simple-auth's session object (which could be a service.. idk)